# Are points in Elliptic curve uniformly distributed?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I need to find an isolated point in an elliptic curve that has the farthest distance from other points.

For example, if we take an elliptic curve $E_{13}(a,b)$, then according to Hasse's theorem, the possible number of points $\#E(p)$ lies between $(13+1-\sqrt(13),13+1+\sqrt(13)) \approx (11,17)$. Considering the worst case, we take $\#E(13)=11$. One of the points is $(0,0)...1^{st} point$. Since elliptic curve points often come in pairs let us take the other points as

$(1,y_1)...2^{nd} point;$  $(1,13-y_1)...3^{rd} point;$

$(2,y_2);...4^{th} point;$  $(2,13-y_2);...5^{th} point;$

$(3,y_3);...6^{th} point;$   $(3,13-y_3);...7^{th} point;$

$(4,y_4);...8^{th} point;$   $(4,13-y_4)...9^{th} point;$

The remaining two points be $(12,y_5)...10^{th} point;$   $(12,13-y_5)...11^{th} point$.

In the recent experiments I have performed, I have found no such curve where a cluster of points exist farthest away from an isolated point pair.

My question: Is there an Elliptic Curve that exhibits such a characteristic ?

OR

Are points in an elliptic curve always uniformly distributed ?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as [your previous one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/38128/finding-the-largest-gap-between-the-x-coordinates-of-all-points-on-an-elliptic-c)?

Comment: Maybe you would get more answers if you described the purpose of finding gaps in elliptic curve coordinates (unless you're doing it for its own sake, I guess). There is some work out there already on gaps in quadratic residues, which might help you since the y coordinate must be a quadratic residue (a square mod p).

Comment: @CodesInChaos I am sorry. But unfortunately yes..!!

Comment: @user13741 I am trying to find the anomalies of the behaviour of elliptic curve. It's my college project and the deadline is near.

Comment: @Sandy, Anomalous curves and invalid points attacks on elliptic curves may be helpful for you to find the anomalies behavior of elliptic curves.